# How to access Kotlin object from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, kotlin, kotlin-interop, kotlin-js-interop

I'm using kotlin2js to generate JS library from Kotlin code. I'm then using this library in Javascript (not Kotlin). The code has some Kotlin objects and some normal classes. I can access normal classes from Javascript, but I can't access the objects in any way.

The [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/js-to-kotlin-interop.html) is pretty sparse, only relevant line might be this:

> Kotlin preserves lazy object initialization in JavaScript.

I'm not sure what that means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that Kotlin changed name of the method to something like this: `calculate_ywek2$()`. And it's very hard to figure out, because Kotlin doesn't generate Typescript definitions, so autocomplete doesn't work. The name can be changed with `@JsName` annotation.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you should specify moduleName as well when accessing from javascript.

Comment: I figured it out, see my answer.